# Azure IoT Explorer No Longer Getting Device Telemetry

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

My Azure IoT Explorer used to work but all of a sudden it stopped working. The device says its connected in Connection State but it is no longer Receiving Telemetry Data in the Telemetry.

I know that the device though is receiving real data as my Event Hub Trigger is running and the data is being stored in an Azure SQL Database.

I tried to reinstall the IoT Explorer as well and still nothing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using different consumer groups to connect to the IoT Hub? Using the same for both may result in messages not arriving.

Comment: Creating a new Consumer Group and subscribing to it in the IoT Explorer does work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Consumer Group and subscribe to it in the IoT Explorer works. Using the same for both may result in messages not arriving. - as per Matthijs van der Veer